# Баг с календарем посещений сайта

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, страница-учётной-записи

Календарь посещений в профиле работает не корректно (открывается только со второго раза и на английском языке). Шаги воспроизведения:

1. Открываем свой профиль на вкладке "Профиль" (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh?tab=profile)
2. Нажимаем на календарик с надписью "На сайте XXX дней, из них YYY подряд"
3. Ничего не происходит (иногда видно мелькание загрузки, но сам календарь не открывается)
4. Повторно нажимаем на календарь (или надпись)
5. Календарь посещений открывается нормально

OS: Windows 7
Браузер: Google Chrome, Версия 43.0.2357.124 m

В консоли браузера видно, что при первом нажатии пытается (неудачно) загрузиться https://ru.stackoverflow.com/content/js/third-party/jquery-ui/datepicker-ru.js. Т.к. загрузка этого файла была неудачной, то при следующей попытке открывается дефолтный календарь (на английском языке).

При неудачной попытке загрузки `datepicker-ru.js` (например, если добавить его проблематично), логично было бы открывать дефолтный календарь сразу же, а не со второй попытки.

На картинке консоль и сеть хрома:

[image: Консоль и сеть хрома]

Comment: Воспроизводится на FF/Win7.

Comment: @VladD, должно везде воспроизводиться, т.к., судя по всему, проблема в том, что файла `datepicker-ru.js` не существует, и это не обрабатывается должным образом.

Comment: Спасибо! Добавил в базу дефектов.